# EgisTec Fingerprint Scanner Won't Work with Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, login

I have a built-in fingerprint scanner for my laptop - the EgisTec ES603. It shows up in device manager, and I have a driver for it (Windows seems to think it's the latest driver, and I have no evidence to the contrary). However, when I start up the "use your fingerprint with windows" program/feature (Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Biometric Devices) it says "Windows did not find any biometric devices on this computer. You might need to attach your device of install device drivers." I am able to use the same reader on the same computer to register prints on Win 8.1. (I "downgraded" to 7 because 8.1 didn't have the group policy editor unless you bought pro.)

EDIT: Note that 8.1 does have a slightly more recent driver available (3.2.x as opposed to 7's 3.0.x)

Comment: What's the laptop exact model? What's the [hardware ID](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID) displayed in the Device Manager? Which driver version are you currently using?

Comment: @and31415 The computer is a customized version of the Digital Storm Krypton. Hardware ID for the fingerprint reader is:
USB\VID_1C7A&PID_0603&REV_0200
USB\VID_1C7A&PID_0603

Comment: @and31415 I forgot, the driver version is 3.0.14.0

Comment: @and31415 The driver came from Windows Update, the reader is working fine, and I'm not sure what to look for in the event viewer. I can tell you that there have been several events from the source "FPSensor" saying "Add Device success." but there are no events in Microsoft>Windows>Biometrics.

Comment: @and31415 Does the software has to be EgisTec's, designed specifically for this reader? Or can it be any fingerprint management software?

Comment: No, it must be specific; EgisTec solution is called BioExcess. From what I read, the Digital Storm laptops are built by Clevo/MSI and rebranded (possibly customized, too). I was able to find a related driver package in the Clevo website which should work. First of all, [create a restore point](http://bit.ly/XHIuEj) - just in case. Visit [this page](http://bit.ly/1mAbhA7) and download "Egistec fingerprint driver (3.0.15.0) for Windows 8.1 64-bit version." (ignore the name, it's actually meant for XP and later) Uninstall the current driver, restart, install the software, and restart when done.

Comment: @and31415 10/10!!! I only saw BioExcess on EgisTec's website, where it costs $40. If you could post your last comment as an answer, I will gladly upvote and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

In order for the fingerprint scanner to be fully recognized, the device driver is not enough: you need a specific management software. EgisTec solution is called [BioExcess](http://www.egistec.com/en/products/bioexcess.aspx).

From what I read, the Digital Storm laptops are built by Clevo/MSI and then rebranded (possibly customized, too). I was able to find a software package in the official Clevo website which should do the job. Here's what you need to do:

1. Visit the following Clevo support page:
   http://www.clevo.com.tw/en/e-services/download/ftpOut.asp?ltype=9&submit=+GO+&Lmodel=W3xxSK
2. Download and extract the **Egistec fingerprint driver (3.0.15.0) for Windows 8.1 64-bit version** package. The file should be around 37 MiB; ignore the name, it's actually meant for Windows XP and later.
3. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `devmgmt.msc`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Once the Device Manager window has finished loading, locate the fingerprint scanner from the list.
4. Right-click the device and select **Uninstall** from the context menu. Make sure to enable the **Delete the driver software for this device** option, and then click **OK**. Restart Windows when done.
5. Install the software you previously downloaded, then restart Windows again.

---

## Additional information

> Windows 8.1 includes a fingerprint registration application, thereby removing the need for a hardware manufacturer to provide such an application. This application is integrated with the account settings page in PC settings.
>
> <sub>Source: [What's New in Biometrics in Windows 8.1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn344916.aspx)</sub>

### Further reading

- [Fingerprint reader displays in device manager, not in biometric devices](http://9z.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=16)
- [Introduction to the Windows Biometric Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn613952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: New link location: [Fingerprint reader displays in device manager, not in biometric devices](http://www.9z.com/?p=3351)